# am getting a error in pyvirtualdisplay

Tags: python

when i run the  python script it shows error like this,i want to know the procedure or any way to solve these error.can anyone help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bus1.py", line 19, in <module>
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600),use_xauth=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 38, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 33, in __init__
    AbstractDisplay.__init__(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py", line 40, in __init__
    raise xauth.NotFoundError()
pyvirtualdisplay.xauth.NotFoundError
```

Comment: With the question getting -5 votes, I assume you are new to StackOverflow and programming itself., Kindly spend more time on reading the error message properly and google for the resolution of the same.

Answer (score 2):

Check [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay).

> xauth
>
> Some programs require a functional Xauthority file. `PyVirtualDisplay` can generate one and set the appropriate environment variables if you pass `use_xauth=True` to the Display constructor. Note however that this feature needs `xauth` installed, otherwise a `pyvirtualdisplay.xauth.NotFoundError` is raised.

If you are using `apt-get`, try:

`sudo apt-get install xauth`

If you are using Arch, try:

`sudo pacman -S xorg-auth`

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you did much research.. the [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) page says this.

> Some programs require a functional Xauthority file. PyVirtualDisplay can generate one and set the appropriate environment variables if you pass use_xauth=True to the Display constructor. Note however that this feature needs xauth installed, otherwise a pyvirtualdisplay.xauth.NotFoundError is raised.

So .. go install xauth :)